# Can you have a single logical <form> split across multiple <div>s?

Tags: html

In my existing web page layout, which involves multiple files, one specifying the high-level layout, there are two  elements, one for a left column, and one for a right column.

I want to have a single logical `<form>` (with a single action) where `<input>` elements are spread across both the left column and the right column. Is the only way to do this have the  element be parent to both `<div>`s (and refactor my layout code), or is it possible to do something like `<form [something]>` inside both divs, so that clicking submit in one form submits all the inputs from both forms?

Comment: Why do you need or want to create a "logical" form element? Is it because the two columns are present in different HTML files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way to submit both forms is to  wrap both `<div>`s within a single `<form>` tag. Or, you can use jQuery/JavaScript to aggregate the data and submit them together as one submission.

Comment: doesn't really answer the question, the question is - is that the only way?

Comment: Updated my answer for you.

Comment: Thanks, the javascript approach sounds interesting, got a link?

Comment: No but with jQuery it isn't hard. Just serialize both form data and send them together. It would be one extra line of code.

Answer (score 10):

I think people are missing the question. A `<form>` can contain whatever elements it needs. If the layout of your page is something like:

```
<body>
    <div id="leftColumn"><input name="foo" type="text"></div>
    <div id="rightColumn"><input name="bar" type="text"></div>
<body>
```

You don't need separate `foo` and `bar` forms. You can happily encase both of those `<div>`s inside a single `<form>` element:

```
<body>
    <form name="onlyOneForm">
        <div id="leftColumn"><input name="foo" type="text"></div>
        <div id="rightColumn"><input name="bar" type="text"></div>
    </form>
<body>
```

Comment: As asker of question, what was wanting was not separate foo and bar forms, I want one logical form where ALL data is submittted to a single action. You probably wonder at my motivation for splitting it into pieces, the answer is simply that would work better with my existing layout code.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. That's why I posted this. I'll rephrase: The `<form>` element is (by default) not "displayed"; it does not affect layout in any way. You can put literally whatever you want inside a `<form>`, including layout elements, inputs, controls, scripts... Point is, you don't need to divide your form or place inputs outside of it in order to achieve a certain layout or style. Unless you are nesting forms (as mentioned in your answer, but not in your question), all you need to do is make sure the inputs are all within the `<form>`.

Answer (score 9):

(Sorry to unaccept an answer and post my own, but I just found out apparently the answers I got are not up to date with HTML5!)

HTML5 introduces a `form=` attribute for `<input>` element [1]. So that you can do `<input form="form1" name="input1" /> and have it in a nested inner form, or even outside of the`` element.

[1] http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fae-form

Comment: Be very careful about taking your information from w3schools. It is [very often wrong](http://w3fools.com). In this case, beware that it says "To refer to more than one form, use a space-separated list of form ids." This is wrong - there is no provision for a space separated list for the form attribute.

Comment: That link gives a 404

Comment: That does work but it does not work for any version of IE. So use if you can discard your IE users.

Comment: Best answer when you want to separate the submit button from the form itself.

Comment: @Alohci is correct that you cannot refer to more than one form, however, the w3fools.com link referenced has been updated to reflect the fact that w3schools has corrected the majority of their erroneous information.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is **No**, you cannot have two separate `form` tags acting as a 1 form, instead wrap the whole thing inside a wrapping div tag

```
<form>
  <!-- some content with input elements has no relation with other form tag on this page, it just ends where you specify the end tag -->
</form>

<form>
  <!-- Has  no relation with the first form -->
</form>
```