# Forms split across DIVs - CSS doesn't work

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a form that doesn't end before the **DIV** tag it is in ends.  It validates fine in CSS and HTML validators, but I am having a problem with the CSS of some of the fields. If you see the HTML, I have split the form into two columns.  The **form** and **fieldset** tags start in the left column and are closed in the right column.  For some reason, the CSS doesn't seem to apply to the fields in the right columns.

[This SO Question and it's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884204/can-you-have-a-single-logical-form-split-across-multiple-divs) don't have a solution for my problem.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Welcome</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css" type="text/css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/new.css" type="text/css" media="all">
 </head>
<body>
<div class="container_24">
    <article id="content">
        <ul>
            <li id="Shipping">
                <div class="wrapper baseform line2">
                <div id="information">
                    <span class="bg"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_6 prefix_1 omega">
                    <h2>Shipping & Billing</h2>
                    <form action="billing.php#!/Billing" method="post" id="GenericForm">
                      <fieldset>
                        <h3>Shipping Information</h3>
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <div class="floatleft">
                                <label id="lblfname">
                                <span class="bg"><input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" value="" placeholder="First Name:" class="input"></span></label></div>
                            <div class="floatleft">
                                <label id="lbllname">
                                <span class="bg"><input id="lname" name="lname" type="text" value="" placeholder="Last Name:" class="input"></span></label></div>
                            <div class="floatleft">
                                <label><span></span></label></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <div class="floatleft">
                                <label id="lblEmail">
                                <span class="bg"><input id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="" placeholder="Email:" class="input"></span>
                                <span class="error">*This is not a valid email address.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span> </label>
                           </div>
                            <div class="floatleft">
                                <label id="lblMobilePhone">
                                <span class="bg"><input id="MobilePhone" name="MobilePhone" type="text" value="" placeholder="Mobile Phone:" class="input"></span>
                                <span class="error">*This is not a valid phone number.</span></label></div>
                            <div class="floatleft">
                                <label id="lblOtherPhone">
                                <span class="bg"><input id="OtherPhone" name="OtherPhone" type="text" value="" placeholder="Other Phone:" class="input"></span>
                                <span class="error">*This is not a valid phone number.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span> </label></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <div class="floatleft">
                                <label id="lblAddress1">
                                <span class="bg"><input id="Address1" name="Address1" type="text" value="" placeholder="Address Line1:" class="input"></span>
                                <span class="error">*This is not a valid URL.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span> </label></div>
                            <div class="floatleft">
                                <label id="lblAddress2">
                                <span class="bg"><input id="Address2" name="Address2" type="text" value="" placeholder="Address Line2:" class="input"></span></label></div>
                            <div class="floatleft">
                                <label id="lblCity">
                                <span class="bg"><input id="City" name="City" type="text" value="" placeholder="City:" class="input"></span></label></div>
                           </div>
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <div class="floatleft">
                                <label id="lblState">
                                <span class="bg"><input id="State" name="State" type="text" value="" placeholder="State:" class="input"></span>
                                <span class="error">*This is not a valid URL.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span> </label></div>
                            <div class="floatleft">
                                <label id="lblPostalCode">
                                <span class="bg"><input id="PostalCode" name="PostalCode" type="text" value="" placeholder="PostalCode:" class="input"></span></label></div>
                            <div class="floatleft">
                                <label id="lblCountry">
                                <span class="bg"><input id="Country" name="Country" type="text" value="" placeholder="Country:" class="input"></span></label></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="showright">
                    <div id="messages">
                        <h3>Billing Options</h3>
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="PayWPayPal" value="PayWPayPal"><label for="PayWPayPal">Pay using PayPal Balance</label>
                            <br />
                            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="PayWCC" value="PayWPayPal"><label for="PayWCC">Pay using Credit Card</label>
                        </div>
                        <div id="CCFields">
                            <div class="wrapper">
                                <div class="floatleft">
                                    <label id="lblCCType">
                                        <span class="bg"><select>
                                             <option value="Visa">Visa</option>
                                             <option value="Mastercard">Mastercard</option>
                                             <option value="Amex">Amex</option>
                                             <option value="Discover">Discover</option>
                                        </select></span> </label></div>
                                <div class="floatleft">
                                    <label id="lblCCNum">
                                    <span class="bg"><input id="CCNum" name="CCNum" type="text" value="" placeholder="xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx" class="input"></span> </label></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="wrapper">
                                <div class="floatleft">
                                    <label id="lblCCExpiration">
                                    <span class="bg"><input id="CCExpiration" name="CCExpiration" type="text" value="" placeholder="MM/YY" class="input"></span></label></div>
                                <div class="floatleft">
                                    <label id="lblCVV">
                                    <span class="bg"><input id="CVV" name="CVV" type="text" value="" placeholder="CVV" class="input"></span></label></div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapper">
                            <div class="btns"><strong><input name="Pay" type="submit" class="button1" value="Confirm Quantities and Pay"></strong></div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</article>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
a, abbr, acronym, address, applet, article, aside, audio,
b, blockquote, big, body,
center, canvas, caption, cite, code, command,
datalist, dd, del, details, dfn, dl, div, dt, 
em, embed,
fieldset, figcaption, figure, font, footer, form, 
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hgroup, html,
i, iframe, img, ins,
kbd, keygen,label, legend, li, meter, nav,
object, ol, output, p, pre, progress,
q, s, samp, section, small, span, source, strike, strong, sub, sup,
table, tbody, tfoot, thead, th, tr, tdvideo, tt, u, ul, 
var{
background: transparent;
border: 0 none;
font-size: 100%;
margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
vertical-align: top; }

ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}
* { border:none}

article, aside, audio, canvas, command, datalist, details, embed, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, keygen, meter, nav, output, progress, section, source, video{ display: block; }
mark, rp, rt, ruby, summary, time{ display: inline }

.left { float:left;}
.right { float:right;}
.wrapper {width:100%; overflow:hidden;}
.relative{ position:relative;}

body{ background: url(../images/bg.gif) center top repeat #100f10; border:0; font:13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#717171; line-height:22px; min-width:960px; overflow:hidden}
.container_24 {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 1260px;
height:50px;
}
h2{ font-size:25px; color:#26251e; line-height:1.2em; padding: 0 0 27px 0; letter-spacing:-1px;}
.grid_6,
.grid_24 {
display:inline;
float: left;
position: relative;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
}
.container_24 .prefix_1 {
padding-left:40px;
}
.floatleft {
width: 260px;
float: left;
margin: 5px;
}
.floatright {
float: right;
margin: 5px;
}
#showright {
float:right;
width:390px;
margin:2px;
position:relative;
}
.baseform {
width:850px;
float:left;
}
#messages {
height:200px;
margin:100px 30px;
}
#information {
z-index:9;
background-color:#FFFF99;
height:200px;
width:200px;
position:absolute;
display:none;
}
#content > ul{ margin:0 7px 0 5px; position:relative; margin-top:0px; z-index:1;}
#content > ul > li{ background:#fafafa; height:556px; width:100%; padding-top:60px; position:relative;}
.label { margin:0; width:320px; height:17px; background:#CCC; padding:6px 12px;color:#717171; font:13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.line2{ background:url(../images/line_vert1.gif) 845px 0 repeat-y;}
#GenericForm{ padding-top:7px; position:relative;}
#GenericForm .wrapper{ overflow:inherit; min-height:37px; width:900px;}
#GenericForm .success{ padding:15px 30px; display:none; background:#26251e; color:#fff; top:150px; left:0; right:0; position: absolute; z-index:2}
#GenericForm label{ position:relative;min-height:31px; display: inline-block; z-index:1;}
#GenericForm .message{ height:250px;}
#GenericForm  span{ display:block}
#GenericForm .error, #GenericForm .empty{ font-size:10px; color:#26251e; line-height:14px; display:none; width:100%}
#GenericForm a{ margin-right:15px; float: left; width:63px; text-align:center}
#GenericForm .input { margin:0;width:204px; height:17px; background: none; padding:6px 12px;color:#717171; font:13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
#GenericForm .inputoptional { margin:0;width:204px; height:17px; background: #FFC; padding:6px 12px;color:#717171; font:13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
#GenericForm textarea { overflow: auto; margin:0;width:204px; height:258px; background: none; padding:7px 12px;color:#717171; font:13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
#GenericForm  .bg{ background:#f2f2f2; border:1px solid #fff; border-top:1px solid #c4c4c4; border-left:1px solid #c4c4c4; float:left;}
.button1{ display:inline-block; font-size:12px; color:#fff; text-transform:uppercase; line-height:33px; position:relative; background:#393436;}
.button1:hover{ color:#FF9}
.button1 span{ position: absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:#e54d26}
.button1 strong{ position:relative; padding:0 11px;}
```

So how do I fix this?  Is there something wrong in the layout I am using.
*Please note that the actual page is more complex (and is in PHP), I have extracted some of it to demonstrate the problem.*

Comment: A lot of work, but all the div inside the form should be changed to span, and the CSS edited accordingly.

Comment: Definitely start with validating the HTML. [W3 HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: I have validated the code (using that same link) and it validates fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem:**

It is illegal syntax to close a parent element before its child elements are closed. When working with HTML it is important to always follow a LOFC (Last Opened First Closed) approach.

**The solution:**

Make the `<form>` element the parent rather than the divs. It is perfectly fine to place nearly all of your elements inside of the form element.

Comment: "illegal syntax to close a parent element before its child elements are closed" but does that apply to non-style elements?

Comment: It applies to all elements. Do a search on `well-formed HTML elements` for further info. Technically there is no such thing as style vs non-style elements (at least since CSS has been adopted). HTML elements define the structure of your document and while they each have a default style it is ultimately CSS that should be used to define the style of your document. Also, you had mentioned that your code works fine in a validator. As your code is not well-formed it should fail a validator. I just pasted your HTML code into the W3 validator and it comes up with 5 errors.

Comment: Hmm, I might have posted interim code, but with the form element split across divs, the W3 validator passed it.  However, Firefox View Source did highlight the form and fieldset tags in red.

Comment: I would be interested in seeing the code that passed the validation. The W3 service does report errors on HTML documents that are not well-formed and if Firefox detected it then the W3 validator should have as well.